# Custom IBOutlet property to link with IBAction

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, ibaction, iboutlet

Is it possible to have IBAction property (like `touchUpInside` in `UIButton`?) for my custom view so I could link it with IBAction in Interface Builder?

It should look similar to this in my view header file:

```
@property IBOutlet <IBAction_type> myCustomIBAction;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view controller's interface declaration, define a method with a return type of `IBAction` that takes single parameter of type `id`:

```
- (IBAction)buttonWasTapped:(id)sender;
```

Then in Interface Builder, right-click the button and drag from `Touch Up Inside` to your view controller. Select `buttonWasTapped:` from the popover.

Comment: I want to simulate button behavior in Interface Builder, so I can right-click on my custom view and find there `myCustomIBAction` in context menu (and then connect `myCustomIBAction` with `buttonWasTapped`)

Comment: I have found some similar questions (for example this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792619/creating-event-for-ib and http://stackoverflow.com/a/906811/326017 ) but without an acceptable answer.

Comment: Yes, the answer to that question is correct: you can't define your own events and have Interface Builder pick them up. You can, however, [define your own events and use them in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371785/can-you-make-custom-events-with-uicontroleventapplicationreserved/3494163#3494163).

Comment: Okay, understood... Approach with custom protocol is most accurate workaround.